# First page link issue in Codeigniter pagination library

Tags: codeigniter, url, pagination

For a period of time, I have been dealing with an issue in pagination class.

The problem is that, everything with pagination is okay, except the link of page 1.

All the links are like :

```
example.com/method/page/2
example.com/method/page/3
```

...

but, when I want to go to the page 1, the link looks like :

```
example.com/method/page/
```

and of course it looks somehow awkward.
I want it to look like:

```
example.com/method/page/1
```

How can I fix this issue in pagination library?!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can customize your pagination. Look here for [Pagination Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html)

```
$config['first_url'] = 'method/page/1'; 
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

**EDIT**: To see all list look into `system/librares/Pagination.php`

Comment: but the config u said, is not mentioned in Pagination Guide. Again thanks for help.

Comment: @Afshin yes some of them not in there, but at 'system/librares/Pagination.php` see all the list, also if you need more manual handle extend this library and do whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

As safarov said, I changed my code to look like :

My base_url was :

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'method/page/';
```

So, I changed the code like below to have the first URL as I wish :

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'method/page/';
$config['first_url'] = '1';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Now the first page link is:

http://example.com/method/page/1

I really appreciate safarov's help.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the above answers are correct, it maybe you are passing custom parameters in the GET query string. If so, you'll need something more like this:

`$settings['first_url'] = base_url().'controller/method/?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`