# Codeigniter Pagination: 'First' and '1' has href=" " always

Tags: codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter v3.1.3.In one of my page i'm using the Pagination library.Initially i thought that its working perfectly until i discovered a very big problem with it.

When the page loads for the first time, as expected the current/active paginated record page is 1 with href="".The 2nd page has href="domain.com/section/view/section-name/10".The 3rd page has href="domain.com/section/view/section-name/20" and so on.All the links in the forward direction up to "Last" works perfectly.However when i click the "First" or "1" in the backward direction it does not work as their href still stays empty i.e href="".I don't understand what is going wrong.My Controller method looks like:

```
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "section/view/".$secName;
$config["total_rows"] = $this->Section_list_model->record_count($secName);
$config["per_page"] = 10;
$config["uri_segment"] = 4;
$config["num_links"] = 4;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';

$config['first_link'] = '« First';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['last_link'] = 'Last »';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['next_link'] = 'Next →';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['prev_link'] = '← Previous';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;//<------
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$page = ($this->uri->segment(4))? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;

$data["results"] = $this->Tender_list_model->get_tender_data($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('tender_list',$data);//content
```

Please advice whats wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Friends found the solution to my above problem at

[First page link issue in Codeigniter pagination library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989494/first-page-link-issue-in-codeigniter-pagination-library)

```
$config['first_url'] = 'method/page/1';
```